# Gson-> Json to deserialize List of custom objects

Tags: java, json, collections, gson

I am trying to serialize and de-serialize an ArrayList of Java POJOs using Gson on Json objects
I have an object MyClass as

```
public class MyClass{               
    private int type                
    private int pos;                
    private Object value;                               
}
```

I have an ArrayList of these objects, which I serialize as

```
 List<MyClass> values= null;
 String json = new Gson().toJson(retValues);
```

The json string is

```
[{"type":4,"pos":1,"value":15}]
```

I try to deserialize it as

```
 Type myType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyClass>>() {}.getType();
 List<MyClass> test=new Gson().fromJson(json, myType);
```

I get an error

```
The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@1141ddf failed to deserialized json object [{"type":4,"pos":1,"value":18}] given the type java.util.ArrayList<abc.MyClass>
```

Any input much appreciated!

Comment: I think Object type is the problem.

Comment: The example as you gave it works fine for me.

Comment: Also, you are using an old version of Gson, upgrade to version 2.

Comment: above codes were helpful to me for deserializing to a list of custom objects. using TypeToken  was the answer to my problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added 2 things, I don't know which one made it work.
- I added a no-arguments constructor to MyClass
- I made MyClass implement serializable.

And it works!

Thanks for your help.